Build failed with an exception: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Failed to install the following SDK components:
build-tools;33.0.1 Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1
Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
2


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 8m 11s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Help me sort this error
